# Actual function implementation returns KotlinCValue<AnyObject> instead of specific objective-c type

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I wan't to abstract two classes from their native implementation in my Kotlin Multiplatform project.
The two classes represent a `Position` and a `Region` but I also want to be able to transform them into their native objective-c implementation, so into `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and `MKCoordinateRegion`.

To achieve this I used the `expect` `actual` pattern but added the two functions `toCoreLocation` and `toCoreRegion` which should return me their native counterparts.
These functions work fine in the Kotlin code but the generated objective-c code does not return the type of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` or `MKCoordinateRegion` but just `KotlinCValue<AnyObject>`.

This is my `commonMain` code:

```
expect class Position(
    latitude: Double,
    longitude: Double
)

expect class Region(
    center: Position,
    latitudinalMeters: Double,
    longitudinalMeters: Double
)
```

This is my actual implementation inside `iosMain`:

```
import platform.MapKit.MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance
import platform.CoreLocation.CLLocationCoordinate2DMake

actual class Position actual constructor(
    val latitude: Double,
    val longitude: Double
) {
    fun toCoreLocation() = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        latitude, longitude
    )
}

actual class Region actual constructor(
    val center: Position,
    val latitudinalMeters: Double,
    val longitudinalMeters: Double
) {
    fun toCoreRegion() = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
        center.toCoreLocation(), latitudinalMeters, longitudinalMeters
    )
}
```

And this is the compiled objective-c code:

```
public class Position : KotlinBase {

    public init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)

    open func toCoreLocation() -> KotlinCValue<AnyObject>

    open var latitude: Double { get }

    open var longitude: Double { get }
}

public class Region : KotlinBase {

    public init(center: Position, latitudinalMeters: Double, longitudinalMeters: Double)

    open func toCoreRegion() -> KotlinCValue<AnyObject>

    open var center: Position { get }

    open var latitudinalMeters: Double { get }

    open var longitudinalMeters: Double { get }
}
```

Does anybody know how it's possible to return the native type from the compiled objective-c functions?
Do I maybe need to add `.def` file into the `nativeInterop/cinterop` directory?

Comment: This looks like the exact same question, though I haven't joined the Slack workspace to verify if it was ever answered. Worth checking out though: https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/4690528/does-anyone-know-how-to-convert-a-kotlincvalue-lt-anyobject-

Comment: I requested access to the slack workspace, so I will have a look if it has been answered when I get invited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the value of your object is in a fixed memory position. If you want to to access it in Swift, you need to unpack it first.

To do so, you have two options:

a) You can create a struct in Swift and copy the `cValue` to the pointer of the struct via `place` in kotlin.

```kotlin
// in Kotlin, Test.kt
fun place(
    loc: CValue<CLLocationCoordinate2D>,
    ptr: CPointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>,
) {
    // copy the cValue into the pointer address
    loc.place(ptr)
}
```

```swift
// in Swift
func unrwap(_ cValue:KotlinCValue<AnyObject>) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D  {
    var ptr = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    TestKt.place(cValue:cValue, ptr: &ptr)
    return ptr // the coordinates are now populated 
}
```

b) You can load the `MutableUnsafeRawPointer` while the `cValue` is in a `memScoped` block. For that you need to write a helper in Kotlin, which takes a callback when the pointer is accessible in the memory. This raw pointer can be instantiated using [load](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer).

```kotlin
// in Kotlin
fun interface PtrHandler<T : CStructVar> {
    fun handle(ptr: CPointer<T>): Unit
}

object Bridge {
    fun <T : CStructVar> load(cValue: CValue<T>, handler: PtrHandler<T>) {
        memScoped { 
            //2: the ptr of cValue is fixed here
            handler.handle(cValue.ptr)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
// in Swift
private class SwiftPtrHandler<T>:PtrHandler {
    var loaded:T {
        return _loaded!
    }
    
    private var _loaded:T? = nil

    //3: receives the raw pointer from the Bridge object
    func handle(ptr:UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
        let t = ptr.load(as: T.self)
        // 4: populate for later usage
        _loaded = t
    }
}


func unwrap<T>(_ cValue:KotlinCValue<AnyObject>) -> T {
    let handler = SwiftPtrHandler<T>()
    //1: call load 
    Bridge().load(cValue: cValue, handler: handler)
    return handler.loaded
}

// usage
let loc:CLLocationCoordinate2D = unwrap(cValue)
```